# How to run .py executable under python 3 by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question has probably been asked to death, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I can run python 3 script like this:

```
python3 my.py
```

However, suppose I make it executable and run it on its own. Then it typically executes under python 2, but I want it under python 3. Is this possible?

```
chmod u+x my.py
./my.py     #executes under python 2.
```

Can I add something to the first line of the script? Or can I change global system default? (I'm on OS X).
Also, is it safe to change global default, will any of my applications stop working?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you write

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

as the first line of the file, it will be executed b python 3.

Note that you must execute it as:

```
./my.py
```

if you do

```
python my.py
```

I have no idea what might happen. If your default python version is 2.7, it will probably be executed by that version.

Comment: Yes indeed, this solves the issue. I can accept answer in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all `*nix` variants support the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

So adding it as the first line will find Python 3 assuming the path where python resides is including in the `$PATH`